# Ссылка на Вайбер под разные ОС

Tags: dom, ссылки, viber

Всем привет.

Ссылку на Whatsapp удалось сделать без всяких проблем. А вот с Вайбером сложилась очень странная ситуация: если в 'href='viber://chat?number=380504443338' не добавить плюс в начале кода, то код не срабатывает на продуктах apple, если же добавить плюс, то это проблема решается, зато перестает работать на android. Сайт сделан на платформе-конструкторе vigbo. Единственное место, где я могу интегрировать свой код вы увидите на скриншоте.

[image: Screenshot рабочей области]

UPD

Я нашла следующее решение, которое работает. После добавления ссылке id "newhref" вставила скрипт:

```
<script>
var isMobile = {
Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},
BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
},
iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
},
Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
},
Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
},
any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
}
};
if(isMobile.iOS()){
document.getElementById("newhref").href = "Viber://chat?number=+380504443338";
}
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf ('Mac')!= -1)     {document.getElementById("newhref").href = "Viber://chat?number=+380504443338";
}
</script>
```

Как видите уже в коде, проблема была не только с мобильными устройствами, но и компъютерами Apple.

Буду благодарна за советы по оптимизации кода, так как никогда особенно не пересекалась с JS.

Comment: отличное решение, мне интересно как вы сделали Ватцапп для десктопа ссылку

Comment: @IgorStrelya если установлено приложение, то по ссылке работает одинаково на мобильных устройствах, и для десктопа  -  href="whatsapp://send?phone=[номер]"